# How to transpile a circuit using Qiskit as done in IBMQ experience

Tags: programming, qiskit, ibm-q-experience

When I create a circuit using Qiskit and then transpile it using `transpiled_circuit = transpile(circuit, ibm_backend, optimization_level=1)` then I open my IBMQ account and go to circuit composer to draw the circuit and run it on the same backend, the transpiled circuit I got from the circuit composer is different from that from my qiskit code.

**For example,** I have the following circuit :

[image: Quantum circuit]

when I transpile it in my qiskit code
`transpiled_circuit = transpile(circuit, provider.get_backend('ibmq_athens'), optimization_level=1)` I got the following circuit :

[image: qiskit_transpiled_circuit]
Using the IBMQ experience circuit composer I got the following transpiled circuit when I run using `ibmq_athens`

[image: transpile_circuit_qasm]

I tried different optimization levels in qiskit and the transpiled circuit is also different.

**My question is how I can get a transpiled circuit in qiskit to be the same as the one returned from IBMQ experience circuit composer.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`transpiled_circuit = transpile(circuit, ibm_backend, seed_transpiler=13)` gave me the circuit returned from IBMQ. Also I discovered that even on IBMQ, transpilation is random in most of the backends, in other words, when you run the same circuit many times on the same backend, you get different transpiled circuits.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to obtain similar results to your IQX output using the `routing_method='sabre'` and `layout_method='sabre`' options.

Answer (score 1):

Consider that the transpilation process is not deterministic and the output might vary in every run (`seed_transpiler` sets the PRNG seed).

```
from qiskit import *

circuit = QuantumCircuit(5, 5)
circuit.ccx(1,2,4)
circuit.ccx(2,3,4)
circuit.measure(4, 4)
circuit.draw('mpl')
```

[image]

```
transpile(circuit, provider.get_backend('ibmq_athens'), seed_transpiler=13).draw('mpl', fold=0)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your transpiled circuit you got from the circuit composer is different from that from your qiskit code is because the native gates on IBM's quantum hardware only consists of CNOT, and single qubit gates ($U_1, U_2, U_3$ ); and furthermore NOT all the qubits are connected to one another.

For Athen, you have:

[image]

And so when you execute your CCNOT gate, you must decompose it to the hardware native set of  gates. This can be done as:

[image]

So here when you have a CNOT between two qubits that are not connected, you have to do some overhead swapping which resulted in a much longer circuit than what you orginally have.

This is why part of the Quantum Volume metric is also influenced by the qubits connectivity. Less connectivity implies you have to do more overhead gate execution resulting in longer circuit depth which in turns require longer qubit coherence...

Comment: I consider that the transpile function in qiskit do the required decompositions according to the backend I pass to it as an attribute  and so I should get the same transpiled circuit I got from IBMQ @KAJ226

Comment: @MonicaMagdy The two bottom circuits are the same aren't they?

Comment: The 2 bottom circuits -> you mean the transpiled cirquit from qiskit and the transpiled circuit from IBM .

Comment: @MonicaMagdy Yes. The two longer circuits.

Comment: To be honest, I haven't tried them. But they should give the same outputs

Comment: @MonicaMagdy I mean they look identical to one another from the pics you posted. Just different color..

Comment: no the number of gates is different and also the angles in u1 and u2 and that's my question I want to get the same transpiled circuit in qiskit as the one I got from IBMQ

Comment: @MonicaMagdy I counted 39 gates in both... one uses $pi/4$ and the other represented it as $0.7853..$ which is the same...

Comment: I found that each time I run my code I get a different transpiled circuit. sometimes I get the correct one and then I run the code again I get a larger one with more than 40 gates